# Javascript Text Slideshow Start from Beginning on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added a text slideshow to a div that is called by JQuery on hover.  How do I get the slideshow to start from the beginning each time the user hovers on the div?  Right now it just continues to loop after the first time it is activated.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#mercury .infos').hover(

  function () {
            if($("a.active").is('.mercury')){
                $("#descriptionls").fadeIn("2000");
            };


        var quotes = [
        "Who’s the one who’s always there when that keeps happening?",
        "Learn to dismantle self-defeating behaviors",
        "JOIN THE FLOW TODAY",
        ];

        var i = 0;

        setInterval(function() {
            $("#lstextslide").html(quotes[i]);
            if (i == quotes.length)
                i=0;
            else
                i++;
        }, 1 * 4000);



        });


});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cancel the previous interval and call the function that updates the HTML immediately. See http://jsfiddle.net/xozL96fj/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var intervalTimer = null;

    $('#mercury .infos').hover(

        function () {
            if($("a.active").is('.mercury')){
                $("#descriptionls").fadeIn("2000");
            }

            if (intervalTimer !== null) {
                clearInterval(intervalTimer);
            }

            var quotes = [
                "Who’s the one who’s always there when that keeps happening?",
                "Learn to dismantle self-defeating behaviors",
                "JOIN THE FLOW TODAY",
            ];

            var i = 0;

            function update() {
                 $("#lstextslide").html(quotes[i]);
                 i = (i + 1) % quotes.length;
            }
            // Call it immediately, don't wait until the interval
            update();
            intervalTimer = setInterval(update, 4000);
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi @JuanMendes!  When I paste that in it stops running completely.  Something is off.  But you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @ThesisDesign Another problem is the fact that you're not starting your slideshow immediately. Check out my new solution with an example

Comment: Thank you so much!  That did the trick!  Yes, I knew about the delayed start.  That was next on my list of things to figure out.  It's a very large solar system piece.  I'm up to 20k lines of code.  That's a lot for me as a beginner, so I was going one hurdle at a time.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a check if your slider has already been activated. If you hover over your slider when the slider is already active, you will have to reset $i, and call setInterval() again.